# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(m-k)}{n!} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{m}{n}$ , where $\binom{m}{n} = \frac{(m-1)\dots(m-n+1)}{n!}$ and $m$ is real number. Find the conditions of convergence. My attempt was : representing the sequence as $e^{\dots}$ and find asymptotic behavior, but I couldn't get something good. Any ideas?

Comment: For $n>m$ the summands are all 0.

Comment: @FriederJäckel no, just look on my definition.

Comment: I don't think that is the usual convention for generalized binomial coefficients (which involves the Gamma function). It might be clearer if you just wrote it in terms of a sum of products i.e. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \prod_{j=0}^n \frac{m-j+1}{j}$.

Comment: Usually $\binom{m}{n} = \frac{m(m-1)\dots(m-n+1)}{n!}$

Comment: @Henry that's not true , there will be some negative members

Comment: @openspace: I don't understand your comment. Yes the numerator will be negative. So?

Comment: @AlexR. the problem was Henry tried to represent $(1+1)^{m}$ and that's not valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Gauss' test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssTest.html), this converges absolutely if

$$\left|\frac{\binom mn}{\binom m{n+1}}\right|=1+\frac hn+o(n^{-1})$$ for some $h>1$, as $n\to\infty$.

This is rather straightforward to compute, since, for $n>m$ and $m\notin\Bbb N$,

$$\left|\frac{\binom mn}{\binom m{n+1}}\right|=\frac{n+1}{n-m}=1+\frac{m+1}{n-m}$$

And for $m\in\Bbb N$,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\binom mn=\sum_{n=1}^m\binom mn=2^m-1$$

And so it converges absolutely if

$$m\ge0$$

For $-1<m<0$, apply the alternating test to show conditional convergence.

For $m\le-1$, apply the term test to show divergence.

Comment: First of all, I guess that when $m = 0$ the series diverge.
As I remember Gauss test tell us about absolutely convergency, not conditionally?

Comment: @openspace For any $m\in\Bbb N$ (including $0$ as a natural), then $\binom mn\to0$, so the ratio is undefined.

Comment: And you are right, my bad, it does not tell about conditional convergence.

Comment: I covered the conditional convergence cases now.

Comment: Gauss test does not provide a necessary condition, only suficient.

Comment: @Did Ah, okay, WA made it sound like it was necessary, at least for absolute convergence.